# Saving Multiple Selected Cells in CoreData

Tags: uitableview, core-data

So in the application I'm working on a events ViewController is implemented that requires Users to choose the people at the event for there records. I'm having a hard Time trying to implement it. My code is below.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.devices.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [scoutsSelectedTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device valueForKey:@"name"]]];
    if([arSelectedRows containsObject:indexPath]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [scoutsSelectedTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [arSelectedRows addObject:indexPath];
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [arSelectedRows removeObject:indexPath];
    }

    [scoutsSelectedTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

-(NSArray *)getSelections {
    NSMutableArray *selections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(NSIndexPath *indexPath in arSelectedRows) {
        [selections addObject:[self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

    return selections;
}
```

RootViewController

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
    context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
}
return context;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

// Fetch the devices from persistent data store
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Event"];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"SelectingScouts"];
self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
self.scout = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil] mutableCopy];

[self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return self.devices.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSManagedObject *scoutDevice = [self.scout objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device valueForKey:@"eventname"]]];
[cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Scouts: %@", [scoutDevice valueForKey:@"scoutNames"]]];

return cell;
}



- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [context deleteObject:[self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        UIAlertView *error = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Draft Journal can not delete this event at this time. Please try again later." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [error show];
        return;
    }
    [self.devices removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}   

}



- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"UpdateDevice"]) {
    NSManagedObject *selectedDevice = [self.devices objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
    NewEventTwoViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.device = selectedDevice;
}
}
```

Hope this Helps let me know if there is anything I can add.

**EDIT:**

The problem that is occurring is when I push a row it shows that I have pushed and all of the code works on that ViewController however when I push "Save" on the RootViewController is shows `Scouts: (null)`.

Comment: Your code seems all right, what's the problem?

Comment: @johnMa Basically I want to be able to show the names that were selected to be shown on the Root View Controller but it is not showing up.

Comment: Try setting a break point in `getSelections`method to see what's returned. and I also wondering how your `RootController` know the selections in tableView .

Comment: @johnMa I have added the Root View Controller Code below the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you populating these arrays that you are using?

Are you sure they are being populated?

Did you put break points in to see what is being returned from each of the `UITableViewDataSource` methods that you have implemented?

> The TableViewCell is being populated when the user gets the chance to choose the people at the event. When the user pushes save the data does not transfer into the Root View Controller and gives me NULL

Next question: is your `arSelectedRows` iVar initialized anywhere?  It is not shown in the code sample you provided.

How are you passing the value of `arSelectedRows` when save is pressed?

> I am implementing the MutableArrays like so.

```
@interface NewEventViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> { 
  NSMutableArray *arOptions; 
  NSMutableArray *arSelectedRows; 
} 
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *devices; 
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *scoutsArray;
```

That is the definition of the iVar but how are you **initializing** the `arSelectedRows` array?  If you do not initialize it then it will be `nil` and your calls to `-addObject:` will be called against `nil` and do nothing.

Comment: The TableViewCell is being populated when the user gets the chance to choose the people at the event. When the user pushes save the data does not transfer into the Root View Controller and gives me     NULL

Comment: I am implementing the MutableArrays like so. `@interface NewEventViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    NSMutableArray *arOptions;
    NSMutableArray *arSelectedRows;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *devices;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *scoutsArray;`

Comment: @TimothyRoeJr. Please modify your question to add details there. In addition, provide a clear goal for your question. I cannot understand yours. Marcus statements are correct but if you don't provide additional content is quite difficult to help.

Comment: @flexaddicted I have added what exactly I am trying to do at the bottom of my questions with the bolded letters **EDIT:**

Comment: Would I need to save the Array in Core Data?

Comment: Checked what I implemented now it is working! Thanks All for your Help!

Answer (score 0):

Your `RootController` tableView datasource is the data you query from `CoreData`, Not the user's selections form your `EventController`. So you can't see the changes .you can save the selection state for your entity when user select cell. and change the fetch request to see the changes.

**EDIT:**

1. I assume you have an entity named `Device`, add a new property for it:

   ```
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *selected;
    @dynamic selected;
   ```
2. Set your entity when user selected cell:

   ```
   Device *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
       device.selected = @(YES);
       [arSelectedRows addObject:indexPath];
   }
   else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
       device.selected = @(NO);
       [arSelectedRows removeObject:indexPath];
   }
   ```
3. change your fetch request to fetch selected objects

   ```
   NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
   NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Event"];
   fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"selected == 1"];
   self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
   ```

I'm not sure what you really want by the code you post , but I think this is what I will do if i want to separate entity's selected state.

hope this will help you.

Comment: Can you give a example I think I know what you mean but I'm not entirely sure. I'm very new to Core Data